# How do I sleep the Bash loop for certain seconds?

Tags: linux, bash, loops, unix

Say I have a Bash loop like this:

```
declare -a arr=("ALD89117.1" "ALD89128.1" "ALD89126.1")
for i in "${arr[@]}"
do
   echo "myid :" $i
# I want to sleep the process for 0.1 seconds here!!
esearch -db protein -query $i | elink -target nuccore | efetch -format ft

done > >(tee eutils_output.txt) 2>&1
```

I want to sleep the process in the above loop for 0.1 seconds. What would be the command to do that?

Comment: Note that the `$i` dereferences should all be quoted (`echo "myid: $i"`; `esearch -db protein -query "$i"`) to prevent string-splitting and glob expansion from applying; consider running your code through http://shellcheck.net/.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Thank you, I just realized that.

Answer (score 2):

```
sleep 0.1
```

It doesn't get much easier than that!